# How do I get Omnichannel to use queue-based routing (No skills)?

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud

Here is the setup I did

1. Created a routing configuration[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zJSO.png)
2. Created a queue and associated it with the routing configuration and added a couple of users
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFsvd.png)
3. Created a service channel for the associated object (GEICO Quote)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hREnA.png)
4. Created a GEIO quote and assigned it to the queue created in step 2
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGwkY.png)
5. logged into Omnichannel as one of the users associated with the queue

Expected Result:
The quote created in 4 would be routed to the user as an Omnichannel work request.

Actual Result:
The work request queue for this user remains empty.

So how do I get something routed using this queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'll answer my own question.   The missing element was a Presence Status linked to the Service Channel.   So summarizing what is needed, to save someone's future agony, you need the following:

1. a Routing Configuration
2. a Queue that is associated with the Routing Configuration
3. a user(s) that is associated with the queue (user needs to have a Service Resource and a bunch of permissions -- not gonna go into that here)
4. a Service Channel that supports the same object that the queue supports
5. a Presence Status that is associated with the Service Channel

You do NOT need a flow;  just changing ownership of the routed record to the queue will route the item.